# How to create custom item for ListView

Tags: java, android

I have made custom .xml layout for ListView. Now it looks:

[image: Current state]

But it isn't good, because I have fixed width of layout (250px):

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="250px">
            <ImageView
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
                android:layout_marginTop="25px" 
                android:layout_height="100px" 
                android:layout_width="100px" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#FF8C00" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"  
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                    android:id="@+id/textViewFilmName" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="TextView" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <TextView 
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:text="Director:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="10px" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView 
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                        android:id="@+id/textViewDirector" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2px" 
                        android:text="TextView" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="10px" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <TextView 
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"  
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:text="Stars:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView 
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                        android:id="@+id/textViewStart" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2px"  
                        android:layout_marginTop="10px" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
```

If I don't set fixed size for root layout, that I have got similar:

[image: Bad state]

Code for this like previous example, but "250px" have been changed on "fill_layout". How can I set non-fixed size for element, that he will be shown correctly and will fill all row? Thank you

Comment: use wrap_content for layout_height.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Result is similar Screen 2.

Comment: try using wrap_content for linearLayout2, i guess the height is being limited with your image height.

Comment: Just one note try no use px or you will end with layout problems with different screen sizes. I had that problem recently with my app hasta la vista. It made me think a read about different screen sizes and using dip instead of px. I had to read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you guys. Yashwanth Kumar - your proposal works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the android:layout_height attribute on your outermost layout to "wrap_content" and also for the next LinearLayout (linearLayout2). Then it will work.